# Regex to match all numbers, integer and decimals, without knowing the Numeric Convention

Tags: regex, decimal

I want to create a regex to match numbers.

These numbers may:

- be integers or decimals
- follow the American guidelines (commas as thousand separators and dots for decimal markers) or the European guidelines (the opposite) or even with spaces as thousand separator.

The regex may have to match numbers within sentences with alphanumerical characters before and after. (`13.4% - 13.7%`, `less than 123 000nmol/L`, etc)

The match will combine:

| NAME | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| NUMBER | [0-9] |
| SYMBOL | [,. ] (dot, comma and space) |

| NAME | VALUE | HOW TO DETERMINE IT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DECIMAL_MARKER | `,` OR `.` | -> MUST be only one -> MUST be the last SYMBOL on the right (no other SYMBOL after it) -> MUST be different from THOUSAND_SEPARATOR |
| THOUSAND_SEPARATOR | `,` OR `.` OR | -> CAN be one or more -> MUST be the very first SYMBOL on the left (no other SYMBOL before it) -> MUST be followed by a group of 3 NUMBER -> MUST be different from DECIMAL_MARKER |

There is an ambiguity in that case : `1.123` or `1,123` => no way to how for sure if the SYMBOL is a THOUSAND_SEPARATOR or a DECIMAL_MARKER. But anyway, the regex must match it.

What the regex should match as one number:

```
3
13 
330,1
3.1021 
12 300 
1,000,000 
20.000.000 
1,044.12
1 044,120.12
```

What the regex should NOT match as one number:

- RULE 1 → No SYMBOL next to each other:

```
3..4
3,,4
3  4
10.,2
10.,.2
10 ,2
10..... 2
```

- RULE 2 → No SYMBOL after DECIMAL_MARKER:

```
12,300.3 3
12 300.230,12.3
```

- RULE 3 → 3 numbers after THOUSAND_SEPARATOR:

```
1 3
200 10
200 1232
10 111 22
12,12.23
```

- RULE 4 → No multiple SYMBOL for THOUSAND_SEPARATOR. Stick to one:

```
1 123,123 123
```

- RULE 5 → No DECIMAL_MARKER at the beginning of the NUMBER. Must match here `40` and not `0.40`:

```
.40
,40
```

I tried regex like this one : `\d+( \d{3})+|\d+[,.]\d+|\d+\d+( \d{3})+|\d+` (https://regex101.com/r/aZ6Wax/1) but it's not exactly covering all the cases, especially the conflicts that may exists between commas and dots.
I think there's too much constraints, maybe I should divide this regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example data, you might use:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:[,. ]\d{3}(?:([. ,])\d{3}(?:\1\d{3})*)?)?(?:(?!\1)[.,]\d+)?$
```

The `([. ,])` captures the delimiter in a starting second repetition of 3 digits and the backreference \1 matches the same char.

The negative lookahead here `(?!\1)[.,]` matches either a dit or comma that is not already matched.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yLc88R/1)

Comment: I removed the `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) because the numbers I want to match will be sub-strings of bigger strings. It works fine, except for 3 exceptions. You can see them here : https://regex101.com/r/QMp3OS/1

Comment: Do you know how I could handle these errors ?

Comment: @cuzureau You can use lookaround assertions to allow/disallow certain matches. Do you mean like this? `\b\d+(?:[,. ]\d{3}(?:([,. ])\d{3}(?:\1\d{3})*)?)?(?:[.,]\d+)?(?!\d|\1)` https://regex101.com/r/wm6aiD/1

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. You can edit your answer with this, it would be perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
^\d{1,3}( \d{3})?(([\., ])\d{3}(\4\d{3})*)?([\.,]\d+)?$
```

This regex works on matching:

- `^`: start of string
- `\d{1,3}`: a set of always present digits
- `( \d{3})?`: an optional thousands group with a space followed by 3 digits
- `(([\., ])\d{3}(\4\d{3})*)?`: the **thousands group**

  - `([\., ])\d{3}`: the first thousand part, composed of a delimiter and three digits
  - `(\4\d{3})*`: other optional thousand parts, composed of the same previous delimiter and three digits
- `([\.,]\d+)?`: the **decimals group**, composed of either a comma or a dot and a sequence of digits
- `$`: end of string

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/EnEdoj/1).